Grading and Groebner bases
How to specify the degree or weight of variables in the computation of Gröbner bases in Mathematica? I tried something like below, but 'Weights->degrees' part doesn't work.
polynomials = {x^2, x^2 - x*y, x^2 - y^3};

(*or whatever*)


variables = {x, y};

degrees = {2, 1}; 

(*so that x has degree 2*)

groebnerBasis = 
 GroebnerBasis[polynomials, variables, 
  MonomialOrder -> DegreeReverseLexicographic, Weights->degrees]




I think you need to do something like MonomialOrder -> {{2, 0}, {0, 1}}. I'm not sure how it works, since I don't know what weights are in computing a Groebner basis, but if you go the documentation for GroebnerBasis >  Examples > Options > MonomialOrder, you'll see an example for specifying a matrix of weights.

Why don't you simply put the weights in the polynomials?

This is an addendum to march's comment. You can use a non-singular "weight matrix" to specify weights to the variables. Although how the weight matrix works is not explained in the Document, the first row will serve as a list of variable weights. The other rows will "break ties." You can test how the monomial order is affected by the matrix as follows:
f = Sum[x^i y^j, {i, 0, 2}, {j, 0, 3}];
MonomialList[f, {{2, 1}, {1, 0}}]

{x^2 y^3, x^2 y^2, x^2 y, x y^3, x^2, x y^2, x y, y^3, x, y^2, y, 1}

MonomialList[f, {{2, 1}, {0, 1}}]

{x^2 y^3, x^2 y^2, x y^3, x^2 y, x y^2, x^2, y^3, x y, y^2, x, y, 1}

Suppose the former is what you want. Then
 groebnerBasis = GroebnerBasis[polynomials, variables, 
                 MonomialOrder -> {{2, 1}, {1, 0}}]

 {y^3, x y, x^2} 

